# Move data across database with different encoding in ruby 1.9: "Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, utf-8, character-encoding, ruby-1.9

I have written an application in ruby 1.9.3/rails 3.1.0 which works with mysql as database and utf8 as encoding for everything. Now I have to write some data of this new application also in a legacy database which uses latin1 as encoding. This is my database setup

```
# database.yml
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  encoding: utf8

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  # other params

legacy:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: latin1
```

And these are (a semplified version of) my models

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content

  def legacy_save
    LegacyMessage.create!(title: title, content: content)
  end
end

class LegacyMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  estabilish_connection 'legacy' # actually I'm using octopus gem to do this connection
end
```

When I call the legacy_save method on a Message object two things can happern: the message is saved correctly when it contains only ascii chars or an exception is raised when it contains non ascii characters. I'm try to get this code working, but with no luck.

The exception I got is

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1
```

I've tried with [encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode) method of the string class as in the following code, but with no luck.

```
def legacy_save
  LegacyMessage.create!(title: title.encode('ISO-8859-1'), 
                        content: content.encode('ISO-8859-1')
  )
end
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `encode()` transcodes text from one character encoding to another. If `title` or `content` contains characters that cannot be encoded as ISO-8859-1, then Ruby will raise this exception.

My answer assumes that the `Encoding::CompatibilityError` exception is raised by your `LegacyMessage.create!` line.